# strange rust-lld error in no_std environment

Tags: rust, linker-errors, lld, rust-no-std

I'm trying to use rust-lld to link a custom kernel written in Rust and I'm getting this weird error:

```
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/kamil/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/kamil/go/bin:/snap/bin:/home/kamil/.cargo/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig/build/stage3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Odin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Nim/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/boomer:/archive/ARCHIVE/c3/linux:/archive/ARCHIVE/pycharm/pycharm-2022.3.3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/z88dk/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/s:/home/kamil/.local/bin:/usr/sbin:/archive/ARCHIVE/emscripten:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/out/host/bin:/home/kamil/.config/emcacs/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/nnn:/home/kamil/go/bin:/snap/bin:/home/kamil/.cargo/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig/build/stage3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Odin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Nim/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/boomer:/archive/ARCHIVE/c3/linux:/archive/ARCHIVE/pycharm/pycharm-2022.3.3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/z88dk/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/s:/home/kamil/.local/bin:/usr/sbin:/archive/ARCHIVE/emscripten:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/out/host/bin:/home/kamil/.config/emcacs/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/nnn:/archive/ARCHIVE/alacritty/target/release:/home/kamil/build-i686-elf/i686-elf-tools-linux/bin:/home/kamil/go/bin:/snap/bin:/home/kamil/.cargo/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig/build/stage3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Odin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Nim/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/boomer:/archive/ARCHIVE/c3/linux:/archive/ARCHIVE/pycharm/pycharm-2022.3.3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/z88dk/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/s:/home/kamil/.local/bin:/usr/sbin:/archive/ARCHIVE/emscripten:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/out/host/bin:/home/kamil/.config/emcacs/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/nnn:/archive/ARCHIVE/alacritty/target/release:/home/kamil/build-i686-elf/i686-elf-tools-linux/bin:/home/kamil/go/bin:/snap/bin:/home/kamil/.cargo/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig/build/stage3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Odin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Nim/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/boomer:/archive/ARCHIVE/c3/linux:/archive/ARCHIVE/pycharm/pycharm-2022.3.3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/z88dk/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/s:/home/kamil/.local/bin:/usr/sbin:/archive/ARCHIVE/emscripten:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/out/host/bin:/home/kamil/.config/emcacs/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/nnn:/archive/ARCHIVE/alacritty/target/release:/home/kamil/build-i686-elf/i686-elf-tools-linux/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/gnvim/target/optimized:/home/kamil/go/bin:/snap/bin:/home/kamil/.cargo/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig/build/stage3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Odin:/archive/ARCHIVE/Nim/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/boomer:/archive/ARCHIVE/c3/linux:/archive/ARCHIVE/pycharm/pycharm-2022.3.3/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/z88dk/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/s:/home/kamil/.local/bin:/usr/sbin:/archive/ARCHIVE/emscripten:/archive/ARCHIVE/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/zig-bootstrap-0.10.1/out/host/bin:/home/kamil/.config/emcacs/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/nnn:/archive/ARCHIVE/alacritty/target/release:/home/kamil/build-i686-elf/i686-elf-tools-linux/bin:/archive/ARCHIVE/gnvim/target/optimized" VSLANG="1033" "rust-lld" "-flavor" "gnu" "/tmp/rustcm3FPJ6/symbols.o" "/archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps/shell-e91b1ead495f896e.sys_api-2af3a7608b83c355.4bhx0jy1147mf53z.rcgu.o.rcgu.o" "--as-needed" "-L" "/archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps" "-L" "/archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/kamil/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-none/lib" "-Bstatic" "/archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.rlib" "-Bdynamic" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-z" "noexecstack" "-L" "/home/kamil/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-none/lib" "-o" "/archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps/shell-e91b1ead495f896e" "--gc-sections" "-pie" "-z" "relro" "-z" "now" "--strip-all" "-n" "-N" "--no-dynamic-linker" "-build-id=none" "--no-eh-frame-hdr"
  = note: rust-lld: error: undefined symbol: core::panicking::panic_nounwind::h16c15692d6463ed7
          >>> referenced by intrinsics.rs:2510 (/home/kamil/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/intrinsics.rs:2510)
          >>>               compiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.compiler_builtins.578c66a02b9c8733-cgu.0.rcgu.o:(core::ptr::const_ptr::_$LT$impl$u20$$BP$const$u20$T$GT$::read_unaligned::h3b6c56eaac55cbb8) in archive /archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.rlib
          >>> referenced by intrinsics.rs:2510 (/home/kamil/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/intrinsics.rs:2510)
          >>>               compiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.compiler_builtins.578c66a02b9c8733-cgu.0.rcgu.o:(core::ptr::const_ptr::_$LT$impl$u20$$BP$const$u20$T$GT$::read_unaligned::h48c3b5a4cc6e53f3) in archive /archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.rlib
          >>> referenced by intrinsics.rs:2510 (/home/kamil/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/intrinsics.rs:2510)
          >>>               compiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.compiler_builtins.578c66a02b9c8733-cgu.0.rcgu.o:(core::ptr::const_ptr::_$LT$impl$u20$$BP$const$u20$T$GT$::read_unaligned::h8c7c7d6c241634dc) in archive /archive/ARCHIVE/sources/cos/programs/shell/target/x86_64-unknown-none/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-ec434174929fe3ec.rlib
          >>> referenced 2 more times
```

`rustc --version`: `rustc 1.73.0-nightly (32303b219 2023-07-29)`

`cargo --version`: `cargo 1.73.0-nightly (7ac9416d8 2023-07-24)`

`ld.lld --version`: `LLD 15.0.6 (compatible with GNU linkers)`

I'm working in an environment without the main function and without the standard library. I already have implemented a panic handler and annotated it with `#[panic_handler]`. This error ONLY occurs if I call to certain functions in my code, which are completely unrelated i.e. this error may or may not happen, so it's not easily reproducible

Edit:
I forgot to mention. I'm not using a custom target. the target I'm compiling with is `x86_64-unknown-none`

Comment: Off the top of my head: `panic_nounwind` is a new mechansim for panics that never unwind, even in unwinding mode (for example, debug checks for pointer alignment). I don't know if they need any special treatment within the panic handler.

Comment: Again, I find this extremely strange, since this linking problem only occurs when calling certain functions (written by me, not from core library) and sometimes it happens and sometimes doesn't, so it's a lottery to get this error

Comment: Your functions probably do something that requires those assertions (such as dereferencing a raw pointer). And if I had to guess, this won't happen in release mode.